# Get extension property from user in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

As per the [guidelines specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-feature-directory-extensions) in the Microsoft Azure Docs, I have configured a custom attribute to sync with Azure AD.

When viewing the Tenant Schema Extension App in the Microsoft Graph Explorer 
using `/beta/applications/Blocked_Tenant_Schema_Extension App_Id/extensionProperties`, I can see the extension property has been registered.

The problem is I can't work out how to view this in the Microsoft Graph for a `user`.

I have tried using `Extensions` for a `user`, but can't see it against that.

I have also tried using Directory Object in the Microsoft Graph `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/Blocked-User-Id?$select=id,extension_Blocked-App-ID_otherTelephone`

Answer (score 3):

If you get the user and `$select` the extension, it should be returned.

E.g.:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.com?$select=id,extension_b569610d09e44cddbadeb9beaaaaaaaa_ApiRoles
```

One important thing to note is that the property has the app's id without dashes.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Just tried this in the Microsoft Graph Explorer for a user I know has this attribute set in Active Directory. Is there a way through something in Powershell I can see if it's being set in Azure AD? Thanks